# How to set a pyzmq socket queued timeout

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I had connected zeromq, the "msg_in" already queued. If there is no new message in the period of time the queue come on the set for timeout. how to set the timeout. The following is the core code

```
requestDict = {"id":111, "name":"test"}
zmqConn.mSocket.send(json.dumps(requestDict), flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
msg_in = zmqConn.mSocket.recv()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use Poller for timeouts:

```
import zmq
p = zmq.Poller()
p.register(zmqConn.mSocket, zmq.POLLIN)

msgs = dict(p.poll(timeout)) 
if zmqConn.mSocket in msgs and msgs[zmqConn.mSocket] == zmq.POLLIN:
   # recv there
else:
   # timeout
```