# Reconnecting to ZMQ feed after disconnect

Tags: python, network-programming, zeromq, pyzmq

I have this simple python script which connects to a ZMQ feed and spits out some data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import zlib
import zmq
import simplejson

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

    # Connect to the first publicly available relay.
    subscriber.connect('tcp://relay-us-east-1.eve-emdr.com:8050')
    # Disable filtering.
    subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

    while True:
        # Receive raw market JSON strings.
        market_json = zlib.decompress(subscriber.recv())
        # Un-serialize the JSON data to a Python dict.
        market_data = simplejson.loads(market_json)
        # Dump typeID
        results = rowsets = market_data.get('rowsets')[0];
        print results['typeID']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is running on my home server. Sometimes, my home server loses connectivity to the internet, the curse of being a residential connection. When the network does drop out and come back on, however, the script stalls. Is there any way to reinitialize connection? I'm still new to python, a point in the right direction would be wonderful. =)

Comment: Dynamic DNS?  ZeroMQ will only resolve once which may be your problem.

Comment: I use dynamic DNS, yes. I have a .it.cx hostname pointed to my IP address which is updated on a regular basis on my router. If there any way that I can check via a loop if there is a connection and if not try a reconnect?

Comment: You would to periodically close and re-connect to re-resolve the DNS entry.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is still relevant, but here goes:

Use a timeout (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538988/zeromq-how-to-prevent-infinite-wait), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919372/how-to-set-a-pyzmq-socket-queued-timeout) and [here](https://gist.github.com/RussTheAerialist/2052933)). On ZMQ < 3.0 it would look something like this (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import zlib
import zmq
import simplejson

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    while True:
        subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        # Connect to the first publicly available relay.
        subscriber.connect('tcp://relay-us-east-1.eve-emdr.com:8050')
        # Disable filtering.
        subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
        this_call_blocks_until_timeout = recv_or_timeout(subscriber, 60000)
        print 'Timeout'
        subscriber.close()

def recv_or_timeout(subscriber, timeout_ms)
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(subscriber, zmq.POLLIN)
    while True:
        socket = dict(self._poller.poll(stimeout_ms))
        if socket.get(subscriber) == zmq.POLLIN:
            # Receive raw market JSON strings.
            market_json = zlib.decompress(subscriber.recv())
            # Un-serialize the JSON data to a Python dict.
            market_data = simplejson.loads(market_json)
            # Dump typeID
            results = rowsets = market_data.get('rowsets')[0];
            print results['typeID']
        else:
            # Timeout!
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ZMQ > 3.0 allows you to set the socket's `RCVTIMEO` option, which will cause its `recv()` to raise a timeout error, without the need of a `Poller` object.